# How to do a var_dump for an mt_rand

Tags: php, mysql, loops, repeat

I am trying to return the result from this SQL function

```
<?php

require_once "func.php";
require_once "websockets.php";

//  private $curResultId;
//  private $MaxResult;
//  private $MinResult;

for( $i = 0; $i<50; $i++ ) {


    $row = db_fetch_item("SELECT resultid FROM ResultPackage 
        where ResultPackage.slotid like '%1'
        and ResultPackage.PackageID like '%1%'
        ORDER BY resultid desc LIMIT 1");

var_dump($row);
}

?>
```

However when i run it it returns the following:

```
array(1) { ["resultid"]=> string(2) "14" }
```

How do I correct it so its just 14

Comment: `int + string + int` are you sure what you're doing?

Comment: in php  use dot for concat not +  (is not javascript)   mt_rand($this->MinResult,$this->MaxResult) . ", SLOTID=". $slot_id

Comment: @u_mulder, Funnily enough I'm not sure what Im doing hence why I am posting on a help forum....

Comment: @Fred, thanks for the link. Even when I change the bottom line to var_dump($this->MinResult); Still no results are returned

Comment: you will need to update your question with the new code you're now using.

Comment: There are some irregular quotes in your query so I hope those aren't present in your original source. `‘%1'` should be `'%1'`: Note the leading quote on the first.

Comment: @tadman, thanks, I have corrected this but still it doesnt work.

Comment: Saying "doesn't work" is a form of giving up and it's really annoying to hear. You need to work to find some reason why it's not working. Error messages are best. You need to try simplifying the query until it does work, then incrementally add things back until it doesn't to identify what changes break it.

Comment: The loop `for( $i = 0; $i<500000; $i++ )` with a `var_dump()` at the end will almost keep spamming the console / browser long after all the possible results have been obtained. The number of times a loop may be executed should depend on the size of the result set you're dealing with.

Comment: @tadman, understood. At the moment there doesnt appear to be an error it is just not returning any results.

Comment: What is `db_fetch_item`? It's not a standard PHP function.